# class-validator não funciona em InputType no TypeGraphQL

Tags: typescript, graphql

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
import { Min } from "class-validator";
import { Field, ID, InputType } from "type-graphql";

@InputType()
class CartProduct {
  @Field(() => ID)
  product_id: string;

  @Field(() => Number)
  @Min(0)
  quantity: number;
}

@InputType()
class CreateOrderInput {
  @Field(() => ID, { nullable: true })
  customer_id: string;

  @Field(() => ID, { nullable: true })
  user_id: string;

  @Field(() => [CartProduct])
  cart: CartProduct[];
}

export { CreateOrderInput };
```

Acontece que na hora de executar a Mutation com quantity inferior a 1, não lança um erro

Segue a Mutation que usa esse Input

```js
@Mutation(() => Order)
  async createOrder(
    @Arg("data") { user_id, customer_id, cart }: CreateOrderInput
  ): Promise<Order> {
    // ...
  }
```

A verificação com o class-validator só atinge a classe CreateOrderInput

Answer (score -2):

Descobri o problema, quando trata-se de Fields aninhados, deve-se usar o decorator @ValidateNested().

Ficando dessa forma o InputType:

```js
@InputType()
class CreateOrderInput {
  @Field(() => ID, { nullable: true })
  customer_id: string;

  @Field(() => ID, { nullable: true })
  user_id: string;

  @ValidateNested()
  @Field(() => [CartProduct])
  cart: CartProduct[];
}
```